# Arabic character is shown separated in C# HTML renderer

Tags: utf-8, arabic, non-ascii-characters, persian, html-rendering

I am using HTML renderer 1.5.0.6 for wpf available on https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/
The problem is Arabic/Persian characters is shown separated, for example this code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset = utf8" />
  </head>
<body>سلام</body>
</html>
```

is shown like:
س‌ل‌ا‌م

[image: HTML renderer Arabic/Persian char separation]

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What do you mean by "separated"?

Comment: Arabic/Persian characters have different views, if "س" (pronounced s) is alone it is written as above (isolated form) but if there is another char after that it is shown  as "ﺳ" called initial form, For example سلام (salam) is shown like س‌ل‌ا‌م (s-l-a-m)

Comment: When I run the code snippet it shows سلام

Comment: Yes! that's correct form but when you render that html using c# html renderer on codeplex in wpf  environment you get separated one.

Comment: This page is flagged as malicious: https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=htmlrenderer.codeplex.com&hl=en-US  Is the source code available somewhere else? I assume the problem is that they're not handling UTF-8 correctly, but I'd have to look at the source.

Comment: any luck @user7302270 ?